# CF ORM - Cannot load the target CFC

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, cfc

This one is driving me batty.

I have setup ORM.  When I run `ORMReload()`, I get the following error.

> Cannot load the target CFC productCategories for the relation property category in CFC products.

**Application.cfc** ORM Config

```
this.ormEnabled = true;
this.ormsettings = {
      cfclocation = "_model"
};
```

**products.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="products" {
property name="id" fieldtype="id";
property name="productcode" ormtype="string";
property name="title" ormtype="string";
property name="introduction" ormtype="text";
property name="description" ormtype="text";
property name="image1" ormtype="string";
property name="image2" ormtype="string";
property name="image3" ormtype="string";
property name="deletedAt" ormtype="date";

property name="category" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="productCategories" fkcolumn="categoryid";

//init()
public function init(){
    return this;
}

//getByID()
public function getByID(required id=""){
    return entityLoadByPK("products",'18');
}

}
```

**productCategories.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="productCategories" {
property name="id" fieldtype="id";
property name="description" ormtype="string";

property name="products" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="products" fkcolumn="categoryid";

//init()
public function init(){
    return this;
}

public function get(){
    return entityload("productCategories");
}

}
```

I can get past this error by setting the full path in the cfc parameters, for example `cfc="_model.products"`, but then I get the following error.

> An association from the table products refers to an unmapped class:

Both CFCs are in the same folder. I have tried restarting CF Server. Pulling my hair out.  Any suggestions hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks FLepage and CfSimplicity for your suggestions.

I eventually worked it out to be a permissions issue on the folders.  I moved the whole app to another dev server and it worked fine (more hair pulling).. eventually checked the permissions on the folders of the problematic version and once I reset permissions to give all necassary access it worked fine..

I had copied the files in from a PC to Mac, so OSX must have done something to the folder permissions when I copied the files/folders in.  Not fun.

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

Reload ORM every time you change your model.
Check all names of object and relation name (case sensitively).

Check with "_model" and without on CFC names.

The error message indicates an unmapped class, so one or more names are wrong.
Or doesn't exist for hibernate (reload would be necessary).

Comment: Jlepage. Thanks for reply. Yes, running ORMReload() on every request. From what I can see all model names are correct and same case.   I do get different errors with or without referencing cfc by path. Outcomes of this outline in original post.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your cfclocation setting in Application.cfc to an absolute rather than relative path:

```
this.ormEnabled = true;
this.ormsettings = {
      cfclocation = ExpandPath( "_model" )
};
```